# Test In-App Purchase response.products empty

Tags: ios, testing, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I want to ask about test In-App purchase. I try to get a list product of In-App Purchases But **"response.products" is empty**.

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {

NSLog(@"Loaded list of products...");
_productsRequest = nil;

NSArray * skProducts = response.products;
for (SKProduct * skProduct in skProducts) {
    NSLog(@"Found product: %@ %@ %0.2f",
          skProduct.productIdentifier,
          skProduct.localizedTitle,
          skProduct.price.floatValue);
}

_completionHandler(YES, skProducts);
_completionHandler = nil;
```

}

My code like code in this link. http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial

**In iTunes Connect ::**

- Rights and Pricing : Free , Price Effective Date : Existing , Price
  End Date : None
- Status : Prepare for Upload
- In-App Purchases

  - Type: Non-Consumable
  - Cleared for Sale : Yes
  - Price Tier : Tier 1 , Price Effective Date : Existing , Price End Date : None
  - Hosting Content with Apple : No
  - Status : Ready to Submit

**Before run test App ::**

- deleted App on my test device
- Logout Apple ID on my test device.
- checked Bundle ID in info.plist and AppID to match

Can anyone please tell me if I'm doing wrong. Thank you!!

ps. **Sorry, I'm not good in English.**

Comment: are you initialize the products like this, [NSSet setWithObjects:@"com.domainname.app.FreeAds"];

Comment: Yes,initialize the my products like that.

Comment: hi @FairyloverJen did you solve this problem? i have a same problem here